Cookie Illegal Key error in Python but works in Node
Trying to parse a cookie string in python and its throwing http.cookies.CookieError: Illegal key
from http.cookies import SimpleCookie
cookie = SimpleCookie()
cookie.load("ABC+/=1;domain=.abc.com;SameSite=None; Secure")

In node it works just fine
var setCookie = require('set-cookie-parser');
setCookie.parse("ABC+/=1;domain=.abc.com;SameSite=None; Secure")

Any idea why python doesn't like this format?

According to RFC 6265 and 2616 the "cookie-name" must not contain "separators" incl. /.
